# Issue with starting Lucky server

Tags: crystal-lang, wsl-2, lucky-framework

I've just installed crystal and the lucky framework. I am on windows 10 using WSL2.
This is the error message

```
Unhandled exception: Unable to get file info: '/mnt/c/Python27/overmind': Input/output error (File::Error)
  from /home/sashacode/.asdf/installs/crystal/0.36.1/share/crystal/src/crystal/system/unix/file.cr:44:9 in 'info?'
  from /home/sashacode/.asdf/installs/crystal/0.36.1/share/crystal/src/file.cr:132:5 in 'info?'
  from /home/sashacode/.asdf/installs/crystal/0.36.1/share/crystal/src/process/executable_path.cr:32:12 in 'is_executable_file?'
  from /home/sashacode/.asdf/installs/crystal/0.36.1/share/crystal/src/process/executable_path.cr:49:10 in 'find_executable'
  from /home/sashacode/apps/lucky_cli/src/lucky_cli/process_runner.cr:26:9 in 'installed?'
  from /home/sashacode/apps/lucky_cli/src/lucky_cli/process_runner.cr:22:24 in 'installed_process_runners'
  from /home/sashacode/apps/lucky_cli/src/lucky_cli/process_runner.cr:13:20 in 'start'
  from /home/sashacode/apps/lucky_cli/src/lucky_cli/process_runner.cr:12:5 in 'start'
  from /home/sashacode/apps/lucky_cli/src/dev.cr:5:5 in 'call'
  from /home/sashacode/apps/lucky_cli/src/dev.cr:4:3 in 'call'
  from /home/sashacode/apps/lucky_cli/src/lucky.cr:30:3 in '__crystal_main'
  from /home/sashacode/.asdf/installs/crystal/0.36.1/share/crystal/src/crystal/main.cr:110:5 in 'main_user_code'
  from /home/sashacode/.asdf/installs/crystal/0.36.1/share/crystal/src/crystal/main.cr:96:7 in 'main'
  from /home/sashacode/.asdf/installs/crystal/0.36.1/share/crystal/src/crystal/main.cr:119:3 in 'main'
  from __libc_start_main
  from _start
  from ???
```

Comment: The `/mnt/c/Python27` tells me that there's some confusion happening where the Windows version of Python is being called instead of the Linux version.  You didn't include any information on *how* you installed, so it's difficult to determine what might have gone wrong.  Make sure that you are using the Linux versions of Python and pip, though, and you will probably resolve the error.

Comment: is /mnt/c... in your PATH?  Wonder how bash handles this, maybe a crystal bug...

Answer (score 0):

For Lucky, Overmind is actually not recommended when using WSL2 https://luckyframework.org/guides/getting-started/installing#process-manager

Also see this issue on Overmind for more information https://github.com/DarthSim/overmind/issues/88

I haven't used WSL with Lucky, but I would imagine [Forego](https://github.com/ddollar/forego) or [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) may work better.

For just a little more background on this, Lucky uses a Process manager to boot both the Crystal webserver, as well as the webpack dev server since Lucky comes with webpack (through Laravel Mix) by default.

Answer (score 0):

lucky-cli has swapped to use nox as the process runner so this should no longer by an issue:

https://github.com/luckyframework/lucky_cli/pull/710